# Как настроить в Twig цикл для массива без переменной

Tags: json, twig

Здравствуйте. Я использую шаблонизатор Twig для того, чтобы распарсить JSON в таблицу с помощью цикла [for](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html).

Если массив такой:

```
{"statements:" [{"xxx": "zzz"}, {"xxx": "zzz"}]}
```

То для него работает цикл:

```
{% for i in statements %}
{{i.xxx}}
{{i.zzz}}
{% endfor %}
```

Но если в массиве не содержится переменная, то как тогда настроить цикл? Многие API выдают содержание именно в таком формате:

```
[{"xxx": "zzz"}, {"xxx": "zzz"}]
```

Как настроить цикл для такого массива?

Comment: Подождите, вы не можете использовать twig для распарсивания json’a. И вы работаете с ассоциативным массивом вроде как. Если вам кто-то возвращает просто массив объектов, то присвойте данный массив переменной и передайте в шаблон

Answer (score 0):

```
{% set items = [{"name": "Evgenij"}, {"last_name": "Pasichnij"}] %}
{% for item in items %}
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{item.name}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{item.last_name}}
        </td>
    </tr>
<table>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]